# Appium: Starting an android app using an intent?

Tags: webdriver, adb, appium, expo, appium-android

Does anyone know if it's possible to start an android app with appium using just the intentAction and URL as optionalIntentArguments? This is to test against an expo app in local dev mode running in the Expo client app; I am basically copying what the expo-cli does, but in appium/webdriver tests.

I can get it to work via adb directly (e.g. `adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "exp://127.0.0.1:19000"` but I have to leave out the appPackage and appActivity, which are (I think!) mandatory with appium desktop app at least. I actually hacked in changing appium's validation to not require an appPackage and appActivity when the intent is provided, and then leave that out of the subsequent adb command, which works, but was wondering if there was an intended/official way to do it? I'm happy to PR what I have if not, but figured someone else might be trying to do the same thing.

(If anyone knows how to launch dev expo for iOS I am also currently trying to work that out!)

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of officially removing the appPackage , but i suspect it is possible (I will need to try it).